# Поддержка доступа к Microsoft Access с разных платформ

Tags: c#, access

Здравствуйте! Вот несколько конфигураций.

---

Разрядность - 32 бит

Установлен Access 2010 32 бит

Установлен Microsoft Access Database Engine 32 бит

Программа скомпилирована в 32 бит

Программа работает, без проблем подключается к базе данных.

---

Разрядность - 32 бит

**Не** установлен Access 2010 32 бит

Установлен Microsoft Access Database Engine 32 бит

Виртуальная машина.

Программа скомпилирована в 32 бит

Программа работает, без проблем подключается к базе данных.

---

Разрядность - 64 бит

Установлен Access 2010 64 бит

Установлен Microsoft Access Database Engine 64 бит

Программа скомпилирована в 32 бит

Программа работает, без проблем подключается к базе данных

---

Разрядность - 64 бит

Установлен Access 2010 32 бит

Установлен Microsoft Access Database Engine 32 бит (при этом 64 бит не устанавливается)

Программа скомпилирована в 32 бит

Программа не работает, не может подключиться к базе.

---

Какие есть идеи?
Программа написана на C# в Visual Studio 2012. У заказчика установлен Microsoft Access именно в такой конфигурации. Как заставить программу работать?

Делается две попытки подключения к базе. В первый раз провайдер - Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0, во второй раз - Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0.

Ошибка:

System.InvalidOperationException: Поставщик "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" не зарегистрирован на локальном компьютере.

В журнале событий записей нет.

Comment: Не может подключиться по какой причине? Есть ли сообщение об ошибке или запись в службе событий системы?

Comment: System.InvalidOperationException: Поставщик "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" не зарегистрирован на локальном компьютере.

Answer (score 1):

Запустите инсталлятор ещё раз, выберите режим repair. Если не поможет - повторите с другим инсталлятором.

Comment: Инсталлятор чего? [Access Database Engine][1]? Там нет режима repair, только переустановка. С каким другим инсталлятором? Повторюсь, невозможно установить ADE 64 бит, если установлен Microsoft Office 32 бит.

  [1]: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255

Comment: Под другим инсталлятором я имел в виду акцесс. Но знаете, у меня появилось другое предположение: там, где работает, раньше был установлен акцесс 2007, а где не работает - там его не было. У вас, таким образом, три варианта: а) снести 2010 и начать с 2007, б) скопировать ветку реестра, обозвав её .12.0, и в) использовать .14.0 в своём коде.